# R ggplot2 package: plotting Line (geom_line)over on Bar Graph (geom_bar) from separate data frames

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a bar graph (created using ggplot2 package) coming from one set of yearly data (with multiple y values)and I want to overlay on it data from another set of yearly data in the form of a line. Here is my code:

```
library (zoo)
require(ggplot2)
library(reshape)
library(Cairo)
library(reshape2)
x<-c(2000,2001,2002,2003,2004)
y1<-c(41,62,71,316,172)
y2<-c(3018,2632,2643,2848,2738)
y3<-c(3065,2709,2721,3192,2925)
dat1 <- data.frame(Year=x, y1, y2)
dat.m1 <- melt(dat1, id.vars='Year')
a<-ggplot(dat.m1, aes(Year, value)) + 
  geom_bar(width=0.6,aes(fill = variable),stat = "identity")+
  xlab("Year") + ylab("Water Depth (mm)")+
  theme(legend.position="top")+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white', colour = 'black'))+
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=13),axis.title=element_text(size=14))+
  theme(legend.text=element_text(size=14))+
  theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0.2,0.7,0.5,0.2),"cm"))+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title="", title.position="top", direction="horizontal"))
a
```

At this stage, bar plot is running nicely but when I tried to add line plot from different data frame as follow:

```
dat2 <- data.frame(Year=x, y3)
dat.m2 <- melt(dat2, id.vars='Year')
b<-ggplot(dat.m1, aes(Year, value)) + 
  geom_bar(width=0.6,aes(fill = variable),stat = "identity")+
  geom_line(dat.m2, aes(x = x, y = y3), size = 1.5, color="red") +
  xlab("Year") + ylab("Water Depth (mm)")+
  theme(legend.position="top")+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white', colour = 'black'))+
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=13),axis.title=element_text(size=14))+
  theme(legend.text=element_text(size=14))+
  theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0.2,0.7,0.5,0.2),"cm"))+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title="", title.position="top", direction="horizontal"))
b
```

It did not work and I received this error message:

"Error in `validate_mapping()`:
! `mapping` must be created by `aes()`
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred."

Anyone can help me to fix this issue? Also, any suggestion to add a line plot with each bar in the first data frame?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add argument name `data` in `geom_line()`. Otherwise `dat.m2` is received as mapping to the `geom_line` function.

```r
dat2 <- data.frame(Year = x, y3)
dat.m2 <- melt(dat2, id.vars = 'Year')

b <- ggplot(dat.m1, aes(Year, value)) +
  geom_bar(width = 0.6, aes(fill = variable), stat = "identity") +
  geom_line(data = dat.m2, aes(x = x, y = y3), size = 1.5, color = "red") + # adding data argument name
  xlab("Year") + ylab("Water Depth (mm)") +
  theme(legend.position = "top") +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white', colour = 'black')) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 13),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 14)) +
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 14)) +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0.2, 0.7, 0.5, 0.2), "cm")) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(
    title = "",
    title.position = "top",
    direction = "horizontal"
  ))
b
```

Comment: Many thanks for your kind help! it works but when I tried to apply that for another larger dataset., the graph appeared without line plot and receiving this message "geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?"

Comment: please provide the code with sample data that you have tried so that I could understand better.

Comment: please donot give a data file link instead give reproducible example. [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and if possible post this new problem as another question.

Comment: Ooh Thanks! I did not realize that. I posted new question.